# How to add LocalStorage functionality to my TODO LIST. How and at what points?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to save my todo list items using local storage in js. But I am not able to effectively apply it to the code.

Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/Samimalik/pen/EBRKZv

Here is my HTML:

```html
    <main id="container">
        <input type="text" class="txt" placeholder="Add a task..." title="Write and press Enter">
        <section class="not-comp">
            <h1>Not Completed</h1>

        </section>

        <section class="comp">
            <h1>Completed</h1>


        </section>
    </main>
```

here is my jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.txt').keyup(function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 13  && $('.txt').val() != ""){
                    let task = $('<div class="task"></div>').text($('.txt').val());
                    let del = $('<i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>');
                    let check = $('<i class="fas fa-check"></i>');

                    $('.not-comp').append(task)

                    $('.txt').val('');
                    task.append(del,check);

                    $('i.fa-trash-alt').click(function() {
                        $(this).parent().fadeOut(function() {
                            $(this).remove();
                        });
                    });
                    $('i.fa-check').click(function() {
                        $(this).parent().fadeOut(function() {
                            $('.comp').append(this).fadeIn();
                        });
                    $(this).remove();
                    });
                };
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage wouldn't be the best way to save data here because everything will be erased anyways when you restart your browser, but it can be useful if you don't want your data to be removed when you refresh the page.

First have a look at the official documentation if some of my explanations are not clear : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

So first off all you will need to save a task with localstorage, this is what you'll need to use :

```
localStorage.setItem
```

you could save it with a name like task0, task1, task2,... And then of course the text value of that task.

Then you will have to need a loop that goes through each localstorage that starts with task. This isn't that hard and I'll let you try that by yourself (the best way to learn ;) ).

So most of your code you already have here will be gone. What you are doing here is just adding some dom elements when you add a task. You will have to add those with a loop instead, and run that loop again when you add a task to localstorage.

TIP : ReactJS would be a perfect fit for this, but it's possible in vanilla JS too.

Answer (score 0):

Simple,

To save data:

```
localStorage.setItem('todosData', JSON.stringify(your_data_object))
```

To get data:

```
let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todosData'));
```